# How do I disable the backlighting for the menu and back buttons on a Galaxy SIII?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, root-access, buttons, backlight

Does anyone know how to disable the lights of the buttons at the bottom of my phone?
They are really annoying and I can reach them without the lights on.
I've tried several apps but none of them worked.

I have a custom ROM and I'm rooted. This ROM doesn't show any option for my issue. I don't want to change my ROM because I really fell in love with it.

Comment: Please tell us what ROM you're using.

Comment: Im using Nameless 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GravityBox](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v3-1-4-tweak-box-android-t2316070) module for [Xposed Framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) can do it. Xposed requires root, but from reading your question, it looks like you have root.

- Download [KitKat](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.kitkat.gravitybox)
- Download [Jellybean](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.gm2.gravitybox)

From the [XDA Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/app-gravitybox-v3-1-4-tweak-box-android-t2316070):

> - Button backlight modes (default, disabled, always on while screen is on)

Comment: I already tried that, but xposed framework couldn't be installed due to SDK issue or something.

Comment: Maybe because I have lollipop

Comment: If you have lollipop, you cannot use Xposed. Xposed is not yet supported on lollipop.